# How should I resolve Error: CS8803 on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting used to C# development on Unity, and I'm coming across an issue that hasn't happened to me before. It is one single error, only happening on "void Update()". If anyone can help, that would be appreciated!! (Apologies for my poorly written code)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

float horizontalMove = 0f;

public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour {}

    public CharacterController2D controller;

public float walkSpeed = 40f;

    void Update()
    {
    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * walkSpeed;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, false);

    }
```

Tried getting a 2D Character Movement script to function, as an older one wouldn't work, ended up with a critical error. Had backups and no corruption, luckily, but still couldn't resolve on my own.

Comment: your class define line is wrong.. start there

Comment: This is not C++.... and mostly not C# code either... Could you please clarify why you expect methods outside of a class to work?

Comment: Please provide the *complete* error message, including which line it occurs on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, the best fix would be to move the `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()` methods into your `PlayerMovement` class:

```
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
        float horizontalMove = 0f;

        void Update() {
           ...
        }  

        void FixedUpdate() {
           ...    
        }
    }
```

Comment: "In C#, all code must be inside a namespace or type." Well, not really. Or at least, not in terms of *declared* types. `Console.WriteLine("Hello world")` is entirely valid as all the code in an entry point using top-level statements - and is basically the modern template for console apps. But top-level statements definitely have limitations which are violated by this code.

Comment: Your example Is inside a namespace. It is just in the background. you can decompile the IL and see that it is in a namespace.

Comment: That is just syntactic sugar it works as before in the background...

Comment: merci for the accept :)

Comment: Sure, the result of compiling top-level statement is code within a type (although no, it's not in a namespace - it *is* in a class). But your opening sentences appear to be about *source code*, not the result of compilation. The result of the compilation isn't C#. If someone said "You can't use angle-brackets in C# field names" you'd probably agree, right? But they *are* used by compiler-generated fields. Fundamentally, I think your original sentences would cause confusion to anyone who saw code using top-level statements.

Comment: This is all particularly relevant as [CS8803](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8803) is: "Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations." If the OP removed all the code after `float horizontalMove = 0f;`, that error would go away. I suspect there'd be another one about multiple entry points, but that's slightly different.

Comment: (I'd also suggest using a file-scoped namespace... there's no need to introduce more indentation here.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes the result of compilation is IL and if you are experienced in reading IL code you can see this the namespaces created. You can also desugar it to lower versions

Comment: At least in the Roslyn version I'm using, the code generated for top-level statements is *not* in a namespace. If you just run a top-level statement of `throw new Exception()`, you get a stack trace starting with: `at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)` - no namespace. Likewise, showing the code in ildasm shows no namespace.

Comment: But you seem to be missing my point about the difference between C# and IL, and how confusing it is for you to say "You are getting the CS8803 error because you have code outside of any namespace or type declaration" when it's easy to change the code in a way that *fixes* the CS8803, but still with "code outside of any namespace or type declaration".

Comment: Regarding Unity the only code that actually makes any sense is the bottom snippet .. all others are even more confusing and would be compiler errors as well

Comment: @derHugo it was more meant as a step by step explaination…

Comment: @Jon Skeet agree i have rechecked it and my assumption was incorrect. You don’t need the namespace. I have adjust my answer.